# Build Menu Items From Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am creating HTML Menus from controller. Menus are stored in database and I make html tag as below :

```
foreach (UIMenuModel item in list)
{
    if (item.Controller != "Home")
    {
        string line = string.Format(@"<li><a asp-area=""{0}"" asp-controller=""{1}"" id=""{1}""
            asp-action = ""{2}"" style = ""font-size:16px;;"" > {3} </a></li>", item.Area, item.Controller, item.Action, item.LinkText);
        sb.Append(line);
    }
}
```

which gives me below HTML :

```html
<li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="CrossApproval" id="CrossApproval" asp-action="Index" style="font-size:16px;;"> Cross Approval </a></li>
```

Other Menu Item, Which is written in HTML itself, gives below HTML in browser.

```html
<li><a id="CrossRequest" style="font-size:16px" href="/CrossRequest">Cross Request</a></li>
```

On UI, it looks perfect. However, I am not able to click and navigate to desired controller and action methods. Can someone please help me to identify while this anchor tag is not allowing me to navigate.

Comment: This is because it is rendered as plain string, not the anchor link generated by a tag helper.

Comment: exactly my thought, but how to over come it?

Comment: Which of the two isn't working?

Comment: the one with href is working. Other one is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use RazorLightEngine to convert plain string as rendered Razor string:

```
string content = "Hello @Model.Name. Welcome to @Model.Title repository";

var model = new
{
  Name = "John Doe",
  Title = "RazorLight"
};

var engine = new RazorLightEngine();
string result = engine.ParseString(content, model);
```

And then add it any place in razor view like encoded string

```
<div>
     @Html.Raw(result)
</div>
```

Comment: And how to append this in Razor view ?

Comment: @NareshRavlani did you try?

Comment: I did it using this :
string line = string.Format(@"<li><a asp-area=""{0}"" id=""{1}"" href=""/{1}/{2}""
style=""font-size:16px"">{3}</a></li>", item.Area, item.Controller, item.Action, item.LinkText);

Answer (score 0):

As posted in Question, HTML with href was working fine. So, I decided to mimic the same behaviour from the controller and changed my code as below :

```
string line = string.Format(@"<li><a asp-area=""{0}"" id=""{1}"" href=""/{1}/{2}""
                           style=""font-size:16px"">{3}</a></li>", item.Area, item.Controller, item.Action, item.LinkText);
```

This generated a link which I can click and navigate.

Comment: As you see, it is not manageable and readable. In the feature, it will be so hard to scale current logic